# Размер EditText по размеру текста

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Подскажите как быть. Приходит с сервера строка без (\n, \t и т.д.) нужно программно задать высоту EditText так чтобы поместился весь текст с этой строки. Как это можно сделать? 
P.S. Точно такой функционал реализован в любом чате (Skype, Viber)
Вот код из xml разметки:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/item_chat_relative_layout_separate"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/item_chat_text_view_message_title"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/item_chat_text_view_message_title"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item_chat_text_view_message_title">
        <View
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@color/color_background_view_title_and_text_interests" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/item_chat_text_view_message_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/activity_chat_item_text_today"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/color_background_view_title_and_text_interests"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_chat_text_view_message_title"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/item_chat_text_view_message_title"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item_chat_text_view_message_title">
        <View
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@color/color_background_view_title_and_text_interests" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/item_chat_relative_layout_another"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <com.erminesoft.scadaddle.custom_view.RoundedImageView
        app:setR="21"
        app:stroke="false"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/item_chat_rounded_image_another" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_chat_rounded_image_another"
        android:id="@+id/item_chat_edit_text_message_another"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:background="@drawable/user_bubble"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/item_chat_text_view_date_time_another"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/item_chat_text_view_date_time_another"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item_chat_image_button_twitter_another"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_chat_image_view_message_another"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/user_bubble"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_chat_rounded_image_another"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/item_chat_rounded_image_another" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_chat_text_view_date_time_another"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Date and Time"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/item_chat_image_button_facebook_another"
        android:layout_width="46dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_chat_facebook_selector"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_chat_text_view_date_time_another"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/item_chat_text_view_date_time_another"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/item_chat_text_view_date_time_another" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/item_chat_image_button_twitter_another"
        android:layout_width="46dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_chat_twitter_selector"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_chat_text_view_date_time_another"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/item_chat_image_button_facebook_another"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/item_chat_image_button_facebook_another" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/item_chat_relative_layout_own"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/item_chat_text_view_date_time_own"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Date and Time"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/item_chat_image_button_facebook_own"
        android:layout_width="46dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_chat_facebook_selector"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_chat_text_view_date_time_own"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_chat_image_button_twitter_own"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/item_chat_image_button_twitter_own" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/item_chat_image_button_twitter_own"
        android:layout_width="46dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_chat_twitter_selector"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_chat_text_view_date_time_own"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <com.erminesoft.scadaddle.custom_view.RoundedImageView
        app:setR="21"
        app:stroke="false"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/item_chat_rounded_image_own"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/item_chat_edit_text_message_own"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/author_bubble"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/item_chat_rounded_image_own"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_chat_text_view_date_time_own"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/item_chat_text_view_date_time_own"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item_chat_image_button_facebook_own" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_chat_image_view_message_own"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
        android:background="@drawable/author_bubble"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/item_chat_rounded_image_own"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/item_chat_rounded_image_own" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: покажите `xml` код как вы это организовали. возможно не в `\n` `\t` ошибка. и как определить куда ставить `\n` ?

Comment: У меня с сервера приходит строка с неограниченным кол-вом символов, ширина EditText задана (допусти 200dp в xml разметке) мне нужно определить высоту EditText исходя из пришедшей строки и разбить на нужное количество строк для отображения в EditText

Comment: height="wrap_content" не помог ?

Comment: Высота в xml стоит wrap_content, ширина стоит fill_parent, сам EditText находится в RelativeLayout с параметрами android:layout_width="fill_parent" и android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: стоп в вопросе `TextView`  а в комментах `EditText`  покажите этот элемент в виде `xml`  (в вопросе) а то какая то путеница

Comment: Исправил и выложил код из xml

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте задать параметры величин

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" <!-- Multiline ввод -->
    android:lines="8" <!-- количество строк для показа -->
    android:minLines="6" <!-- минимальное количество строк -->
    android:gravity="top|left" <!-- куда ставить курсор (Cursor Position) -->
    android:maxLines="10" <!-- количество максимальных строк -->
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" <!-- Height определяется автоматически -->
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" <!-- Fill полной ширины -->
    android:scrollbars="vertical" <!-- Вертикальный Scroll Bar -->
/>
```

и еще проверте параметры

```
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_chat_rounded_image_another"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/item_chat_text_view_date_time_another"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/item_chat_text_view_date_time_another"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item_chat_image_button_twitter_another"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

со всех сторон (почти) вы его окружили. И `inputType="none"` установили